# Adding text background color using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, symbology

Is possible to add text background color using python on ArcGIS (ArcMap 10)?

I wrote a function that able to change font color of the string but I want to add background color to it as well

```
def changeColor ([s1]):
  return "<CLR red = '255'>" + [s1] + "</CLR>"
```

Following links show me how add background color manually http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Creating_text_symbols/00s60000000z000000/

Is there a way that I can write a python script instead of doing manually?

Comment: Based on [the current list of formatting tags](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s800000017000000), it does not appear so.

Comment: There is a limit to what can be done with a text formatting tag, the link you have refers to the text properties - not to a tag. To adjust this you will need to manipulate ArcObjects : IFormattedTextSymbol http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFormattedTextSymbol_Interface/001w00000164000000/

Comment: This would be very useful but there appears no mechanism to do this. A background colour could eleimiate many round trips to the geodatabase/arcgis server (label classes currently query the database for each label class)

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> There is a limit to what can be done with a text formatting tag, the
>   link you have refers to the text properties - not to a tag. To adjust
>   this you will need to manipulate [ArcObjects :
>   IFormattedTextSymbol](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFormattedTextSymbol_Interface/001w00000164000000/)